# How do u use ngFor Properties for a inline background colour

Tags: angular

So as the title mentions:

How do I set the background color of a div using my ngFor Loop;

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of entries; let i = index" class="container">
    <div class="block row" style.backgroundcolor="{{x.color}}">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your style property in square brackets, like this

```html
<div class="block row" [style.backgroundColor]="x.color"></div>
```

Please note that style properties can either be in camel-case like **[style.backgroundColor]** or separate with dash (-) symbol like this **[style.background-color]**

Comment: Perfect dint know it had to be camel-case Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it, just need the color to be capital c in `backgroundColor`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of entries; let i = index" class="container">
  <div class="block row" style.backgroundColor="{{x.color}}"></div>
</div>
```